# Time series data storage in mongo DB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, time-series, nosql

I am working on a web services using MongoDB.
What I want to do is have to store date like below using PHP

Initially a collection look like below (insert)

```
{
    timestamp_date: ISODate("2013-10-10"),
    type: “memory_used”,
    values: {
        0: { userid: 1, lat: 12.121212, long : 11.111111, timestamp: 2014-02-12 06:50:30 },            
      }
     }
```

I have to update the above record look like below (update)

```
 {
  timestamp_date: ISODate("2013-10-10"),
  type: “memory_used”,
  values: {
    0: { userid: 1,  lat: 12.121212, long : 11.111111, timestamp: 2014-02-12 06:50:30 },
    1: { userid: 1,  lat: 14.141414, long : 10.101010, timestamp: 2014-02-12 07:00:30 },
    .
    .
    .
    99:{ userid: 1,  lat: 15.151515, long : 12.121212, timestamp: 2014-02-12 12:50:30 },
    .
    .
    .


  }
 }
```

and how to find the latest record(current location of the user).
Can anyone help me using PHP & MongoDB code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is to convert your values `object` into an `array`:

```
values: [
    { userid: 1,  lat: 12.121212, long : 11.111111, timestamp: 2014-02-12 06:50:30 },
    { userid: 1,  lat: 14.141414, long : 10.101010, timestamp: 2014-02-12 07:00:30 },
    ...
]
```

Then you can find the last location of each user by using `aggregate`, `$unwind`, `$group` and `$last`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide me the PHP code to update the query? Insert new user (say userid : 2) in the same day.

Comment: What did you try out yet by yourself? Provide some code! Have you read the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.mongocollection.php

Comment: I will go through. I am using PHP codeigniter rest service framework to achieve time series data storage collection.